# fileupload control does nothing when trying to upload a file with 14mb

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, file-upload

I'm having this weird problem right now and after a few searches on the web I couldn't find anything related to it, basically, when I try to send a .TXT file with 14mb via a FileUpload ASP.NET control it does nothing, the page post back when I click on the upload button but the "click" event doesn't fire

the weird thing is that if I try to send a small file, let's say, 100kb the upload works just fine and the event is triggered the way is supposed to

there's no exception and no error at all, the page simply posts back without firing any event, I even changed the maxRequestLength on my web.config still no luck:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="43200" maxRequestLength="40960"/>
```

I tried to upload via Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox 12, both with the same odd behavior

---

I'm testing it on Windows 7 x64 (IIS 7.5) with .NET v3.5 on an ASP.NET application

---

right now I'm pretty sure it's a file size limitation, I "sliced" the file to 1mb parts and now I can upload it, whenever it goes beyond 1mb it start posting back without firing any event

---

found the solution, the answer follows below, thanks everyone!

Comment: Did you look into the 'executionTimeout' property in your web.config?

Comment: yep, it's 43200 at the moment, it's weird because since I'm testing it locally it runs quite fast, so I suppose it's not related to any timeout

Comment: How about 'maxAllowedContentLength'? maxRequestLength only works for asp.net. maxAllowedContentLength works for IIS. See link here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1169846.aspx

Comment: thanks I just tried that but still happening the same thing, I tried to change to a small value first then I got a "404.13 - "The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length" error, then I changed the value to 102400000, the error stopped but the behavior kept the same, I click upload, the page posts back and no event is fired

Comment: Did you make that change at the IIS level? Also, check to see if txt extensions are allowed in request filtering.

Comment: first I added to web.config, then I checked on iis (request filtering -> edit request filtering settings), there was no txt extension on "file name extensions" so I added it with "Allowed=True" still the same behavior though, I'm restarting iis every time I change a setting just to make sure =P

Comment: Try setting it for the entire server, not just the website.

Comment: again the same behavior, and by the way, thanks a lot for the support ems, I'm trying to find any other explanation as well so I can post any relevant result in here

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately, I'm just about out of answers. Can't say i didn't try :) !

Comment: found the problem, I had to change the "notepad c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config", so I searched for "max" and found an attribute called "maxRequestEntityAllowed", I changed the value to "4294967295", and another attribute called "uploadReadAheadSize" I changed it to "2147483647" and now it's working, thanks again ems305!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the problem, I had to change the "c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config"

there's a tag similar to this one:

```
<location path="YourWebSite">
    <system.webServer>
        <serverRuntime maxRequestEntityAllowed="4294967295" uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" />
        </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I changed both **maxRequestEntityAllowed** and **uploadReadAheadSize** to the values above and the file is now being uploaded

thanks everyone!

Comment: You typically put these values in your local web.config file.